# Cannot find wifi adapter after kernel update to 5.19.0-40-generic

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kernel

I've used the same wireless device for years (Asus PCE-AC88). One day a couple months ago I booted up my ubuntu and it said that no wifi adapter was found. After trying various things with no luck I just upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 which solved the issues. A few weeks later the same issue occured and out of frustration I simply reformatted a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04. Now, several weeks later I've got the same issue. No wifi adapter found. However if I boot to the previous kernel version (5.19.0-38-generic), it works.

I'm not sure if it is the specific kernel version 5.19.0-40-generic causing the issue, or if its simply the process of updating kernel that is causes the issue.

Here are the following outputs when I run it from 5.19.0-38-generic:

```
$ lshw -C network

*-network                 
      description: Wireless interface
      product: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
      vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
      logical name: wlp2s0
      version: 04
      serial: 2c:fd:a1:cf:33:f2
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
      configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=10.28.2 firmware=01-d2cbb8fd ip=192.168.2.29 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
      resources: irq:33 memory:f7000000-f7007fff memory:f6800000-f6ffffff memory:f2400000-f27fffff

$ lspci

02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries Device 43c3 (rev 04)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 11)
```

And the outputs when I run it from 5.19.0-40-generic:

```
$ lshw -C network

*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7000000-f7007fff memory:f6800000-f6ffffff memory:f2400000-f27fffff

$ lspci

02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries Device 43c3 (rev 04)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 11)
```

I've attempted:

```
$ sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-40-generic
```

And:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic
```

Neither worked.

**EDIT #1**: I ran `sudo dmesg` and noticed something, when booting `5.19.0-38-generic` I get the following entries:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep brcmfmac
[    2.718401] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    2.718432] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.827304] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac4366c-pcie for chip BCM4366/4
[    2.842972] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4366c-pcie.ASUS-All Series.bin failed with error -2
[    2.856732] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4366c-pcie.ASUS-All Series.txt failed with error -2
[    2.856759] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4366c-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[    3.782706] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac4366c-pcie for chip BCM4366/4
[    3.782781] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_process_clm_blob: no clm_blob available (err=-2), device may have limited channels available
[    3.783002] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4366/4 wl0: Nov  5 2018 03:19:56 version 10.28.2 (r769115) FWID 01-d2cbb8fd
[    3.810242] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Seems like it tries to load the driver, fails, but then does it again successfully.

However the boot logs for `5.19.0-40-generic` only attempt the one time:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep brcmfmac
[    2.667203] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    2.667244] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.775257] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac4366c-pcie for chip BCM4366/4
[    2.792232] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4366c-pcie.ASUS-All Series.bin failed with error -2
[    2.797133] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4366c-pcie.ASUS-All Series.txt failed with error -2
[    2.797165] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4366c-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[    3.773927] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: brcmf_pcie_init_ringbuffers: invalid max_flowrings(264)
```

**EDIT #2**:

Turns out that the `5.19.0-40-generic` kernel introduced a regression that affects my specific wifi adapter. [This commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/2aca4f3734bd717e04943ddf340d49ab62299a00) introduced a check against the number of `max_flow_rings` inside `brcmf_pcie_init_ringbuffers`, to return an error if it was above 256. My card requests 264. The regression was fixed in 5.19.0-42 with [this commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/ed05cb177ae5cd7f02f1d6e7706ba627d30f1696).

I'm not sure of the correct way of updating to `5.19.0-42-generic`, the latest version in `sudo apt-cache search linux-image-5.19.0-` is `5.19.0-40-generic`

Comment: So, `brcmfmac` module isn't loaded. Can you try to load it with `sudo modprobe brcmfmac`.

Comment: Tried running `sudo modprobe brcmfmac`. No output, nothing changed. I ran `dmesg` and noticed a small different, edited my post.

Comment: Thank you for posting your experiences here. I woke up to my machine behaving in exactly this way - no wifi adapter, unclaimed network. I'm reverting to kernel .38 until .42 comes out. Thanks again!